# Pass localization in iOS 7

Tags: ios, string, localization, passkit

Does anyone know how to localize for different languages a pass(used in passbook) in iOS 7?

I've tried, for portuguese, for example, using the pass.strings file inside a pt.lproj folder way, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!